# Include lua scripts into executable

Tags: windows, lua, lua-5.1

Hi this question seems to be answered but answers don't resolve my problem.
I try to include lua script into executable by copying it into exe

```
copy -b a.exe+test.lua output.exe
```

but when i launch output.exe luaL_dofile() cannot find lua script.
I dont want to use any third party apps to achieve this.

Copying files seems to work because Love2D projects works and I copy files in the same way but i treats them as zip archive (for sake of file hierarchy).

Comment: Why do you think `luaL_dofile` would be able to find a file hidden in a `.exe`.?

Comment: how can i execute file when it is "hidden" ? btw it is not duplicate...

Comment: Im not sure if I understand srlua make lua script executable but what with my exe file will it be included too ?

Answer (score 1):

You can append a Lua script to your .exe but you'll need some way to load it into your program. The main problem is how to find the Lua script at the end of the .exe. [srlua](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#srlua) appends a small signature that contains the size of the Lua script so that the program can read the script at the right offset in the .exe file. Fortunately, the Lua API provides a function to load scripts from arbitrary sources. The convenience function `luaL_dofile` uses that function. You can use the same technique in your own program.